# ASP.NET - How can I build a browser definition file that detects ONLY Googlebot?

Tags: asp.net, browser, definition

I've tried looking at the [Oceans BrowserCap](http://owenbrady.net/browsercaps/) file for inspiration, but it's just a little over the top for me.

I basically need the equivalent of this in a .browser file

```
<browserCaps>
    <filter>
        <!-- Google Crawler -->
        <case match="Googlebot">
            browser=Googlebot
            crawler=true
        </case>
    </filter>
</browserCaps>
```

but I just can't seem to figure this out.  Any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it... here it is for the next guy that needs it.

```
<browsers>
    <browser id="Googlebot" parentID="Mozilla">
        <identification>
            <userAgent match="Googlebot" />
        </identification>
        <capabilities>
            <capability name="crawler" value="true" />
        </capabilities>
    </browser>
</browsers>
```

And here's my MVC ActionFilterAttribute that I use to detect the Goog..

```
Imports System.Web.Mvc
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Web

Namespace Filters
    <AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple:=False)> _
    Public Class SearchBotFilter : Inherits ActionFilterAttribute

        Public Overrides Sub OnActionExecuting(ByVal c As ActionExecutingContext)
            If Not HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Crawler Then
                HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = CInt(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                c.Result = New ViewResult() With {.ViewName = "NotFound"}
            End If
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
End Class
```